# Display Price And Compare Price on collection page

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

1. So I am trying to get display price and compare price of selected
   variant .  I tried creating js function and calling value but
   nothing working here The price is not changing with change in
   variant selected.

```html
{%- liquid if collection.all_products_count > 0 and blocks_count > 0 if filter_type == 'vertical' render 'facets-vertical', results: collection, filter_type: filter_type, enable_filtering: enable_filtering, enable_filtering_color_swatches: enable_filtering_color_swatches,
enable_sorting: enable_sorting, enable_viewing: enable_viewing, enable_sticky_facet: enable_sticky_facet, blocks: section.blocks, filter_max_items: filter_max_items, color_swatches_add_label: color_swatches_add_label else render 'facets-vertical', results:
collection, enable_filtering: false, enable_sorting: false, enable_viewing: false, enable_sticky_facet: enable_sticky_facet, blocks: section.blocks, filter_max_items: filter_max_items, color_swatches_add_label: color_swatches_add_label endif endif -%}

<div class="product-grid-container{% unless filter_type == 'vertical' or blocks_count > 0 %} page-width{% endunless %}">
  {%- liquid if enable_filtering or enable_sorting or enable_viewing if collection.all_products_count > 0 if filter_type == 'vertical' render 'facets-vertical-top', results: collection, filter_type: filter_type, enable_filtering: enable_filtering, enable_filtering_color_swatches:
  enable_filtering_color_swatches, enable_sorting: enable_sorting, enable_viewing: enable_viewing, enable_sticky_facet: enable_sticky_facet, default_layout: default_layout, color_swatches_add_label: color_swatches_add_label elsif blocks_count > 0 render
  'facets', results: collection, filter_type: filter_type, enable_filtering: enable_filtering, enable_filtering_color_swatches: enable_filtering_color_swatches, enable_sorting: enable_sorting, enable_viewing: enable_viewing, enable_sticky_facet: enable_sticky_facet,
  default_layout: default_layout, filter_max_items: filter_max_items, color_swatches_add_label: color_swatches_add_label endif endif endif -%} {%- paginate collection.products by products_per_page -%}
  <div id="ProductGridContainer">
    {%- if collection.products.size == 0 -%}
    <div class="collection collection--empty" id="product-grid" data-id="{{ section.id }}">
      <div class="loading-overlay"></div>

      <div class="title-wrapper center">
        <p class="title title--primary h2">
          {%- liquid if collection.filters.size > 0 echo 'sections.collection_template.empty' | t echo '<br/>' echo 'sections.collection_template.use_fewer_filters_html' | t: link: collection.url, class: "link link--underline" else echo 'sections.collection_template.no_products'
          | t endif -%}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    {%- else -%}
    <div class="collection">
      <div class="loading-overlay"></div>
      {%- liquid assign grid_class = 'grid grid--2-col' if section.settings.columns_mobile == '1' assign grid_class = grid_class | append: ' grid--1-col-mobile' endif if products_per_row == 3 assign grid_class = grid_class | append: ' grid--3-col-tablet grid--3-col-desktop'
      elsif products_per_row == 4 assign grid_class = grid_class | append: ' grid--3-col-tablet grid--4-col-desktop' endif -%}
      <ul id="product-grid" data-id="{{ section.id }}" class="product-grid {{ grid_class }}" role="list">
        {%- for product in collection.products -%} {% if product.type != 'FREEGIFT_HIDDEN' %} {%- liquid assign lazy_load = true if forloop.first assign lazy_load = false endif -%}
        <li class="grid__item">
          {% render 'card-product', card_product: product, card_collection: collection, media_size: section.settings.image_ratio, show_secondary_image: section.settings.show_secondary_image, show_quick_buy: section.settings.show_quick_buy, show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor,
          show_rating: section.settings.show_rating, enable_quick_view: section.settings.enable_quick_view, enable_color_swatches: section.settings.enable_color_swatches, enable_countdown: section.settings.enable_countdown, enable_image_fill: section.settings.enable_image_fill,
          lazy_load: lazy_load %} {% if request.page_type == 'collection' %} {% if product.variants.size > 1 %}
          <div class="product-variant-dropdown">
            <form action="/cart/add" method="post">
              <select name="id" class="product-variant-select">
                {% for variant in product.variants %} {% if variant.available == true and variant.compare_at_price > 0 %}
                <option value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }} - Rs. {{ variant.compare_at_price | divided_by: 100 | round: 2 }}</option>
                {% elsif variant.available == false %}
                <option value="{{ variant.id }}" disabled="disabled">{{ variant.title }} - Sold Out</option>
                {% else %}
                <!-- Handle other cases if needed -->
                {% endif %} {% endfor %}
              </select>
              {% unless product.available %}
              <input type="submit" value="Sold Out" class="product-variant-submit-button" disabled="disabled" /> {% else %}
              <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="product-variant-submit-button" /> {% endunless %}
            </form>
          </div>
          {% endif %} {% endif %} {% if product.has_only_default_variant %} {% if product.available %}
          <form method="post" action="/cart/add">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.variants.first.id }}" /> {% unless product.available %}
            <input type="submit" value="Sold Out" class="product-variant-submit-button" disabled="disabled" /> {% else %}
            <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="product-variant-submit-button" /> {% endunless %}
          </form>
          {% endif %} {% endif %}



        </li>
        {% endif %} {%- endfor -%}
      </ul>


      {%- if paginate.pages > 1 -%} {% render 'pagination', paginate: paginate, pagination: section.settings.pagination %} {%- endif -%}
    </div>
    {%- endif -%}
  </div>
  {%- endpaginate -%}
</div>
</div>
```

Reference image  what i want : [image]

**help me out its how to do this platform is shopify**

Comment: if you share access i can fix your js issue 

Comment: Need to modify some liquid code and Javascript to show the desired results.

Comment: hey @Onkar  if you can please help me out all i have is this much code only and i am newbie in tech.

Comment: hey @HardikSatasiya  if you can please help me out all i have is this much code only for now.

Comment: share your js code then we can find the issue and share you fix

Comment: I don't have any will have create that from scratch .

Comment: hmm, ok sure ...

Comment: Hey dev's any solution on my problem ?